# Valid selection of unit for observational longitudinal regression design, fixed effects vs random effects

Tags: panel-data, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

I have not found this mentioned in any textbook or article so far, so maybe it is obvious and I am missing something, but I would like to know what others think about this.

What is the basis for valid selection of the panel unit when designing a longitudinal study? Often I see it is individuals, countries, firms, hospitals, etc.

I am in a situation where I have panel data (long panel, T>n) with 128 units and a dependent variable that greatly depends on the physical characteristics of each unit. For example, if the dependent variable is the number of potholes per county in a state, a main factor will simply be the miles of paved road in each county. I understand you could include that as a predictor, but what if the only viable approach is a fixed-effects approach where the time-invariant factors are eliminated from consideration?

My main concern is this: the fixed effects regression zooms in on a county (and thus only considers time-varying predictors for each county) and sees a county with a whole bunch of potholes (because it has lots of roads) and tries to develop a relationship between potholes and, for example, temperature, then the regression zooms in on a county with no potholes (because it has hardly any roads) and then tries to figure out the relationship between temperature and the occurrence of potholes. Won't the regression be confused about the true relationship of temperature with potholes? There aren't any roads in the second zone, so of course there won't be any potholes, but the regression can't see that there aren't any roads and will try to interpret the lack of potholes through the temperature fluctuations.

So would a random effects approach be better? I could quantify all of the time-invariant predictors and include them in the regression. One issue is we probably won't be able to get data for all of the relevant time-invariant predictors. I read in Dougherty (2007) that to use random effects the sample must be drawn randomly from a larger population, which mine is not, it IS the population as far as the study is concerned.

I am considering eliminating the longitudinal aspect of the study because it seems like the unit makes the analysis invalid, at least for fixed effects.

Can anyone point me to a resource or provide some advice?

Cross posted (different original question formulation, I think what I wrote here is clearer and more accurately depicts my situation) on [Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1603800-valid-selection-of-unit-for-panel-design), but I didn't get any bites.

Dougherty, C. (2007). Introduction to Econometrics (3rd ed., p. 480). Oxford: Oxford University Press.

EDIT

So, thinking about this, you basically give each unit an intercept, but what about the slopes? Wouldn't the slopes still be affected?